# can't join meshes properly

Tags: boolean-modifier, smooth, remesh

[image]

I want to make a cross and started by making one part, performing an array, sepparate the objects and then i did a boolean to connect these but i don't think that's the way... Already tried to not perform a boolean but just a remesh to connect them but the mesh always connects very very messy. I want the area in between the parts to be more smooth and i tried to make it smooth in sculpt mode but it's still not natural and organic looking. Anybody knows how to "blend" these?

Answer (score 2):

You could correct the topology but if you want it to be clean from the start you could prepare one branch with a topology like that:

[image]

Mirror it with an empty as *Mirror Object* that you rotate 45° on Y, enable *Axis, Bisect* and *Flip* on X:

[image]

Add a second *Mirror* modifier with a second empty as *Mirror Object* that you rotate 135° on Y and again enable *Axis, Bisect* and *Flip* on X:

[image]

Apply the modifiers, bevel the joints:

[image]

Result with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfect! Thank you